# mvc 3 - Model with multiple IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ienumerable, inner-join

I'm looking for the best approach to my problem.

I need to display the names only of 3 different entities, not the rest of the information.

Entities are:

`db.TR{TRID, ProjectID, TemplateID, version}`
`db.Project{ProjectID, ProjectName}`
`db.Template{TemplateID, TemplateName}`

I would like the best approach to display all the results in a grid like this:

`TRID - ProjectName - TemplateName - Version`

I would like to know how you would do the Model, Controller(Index Function) and the view.

So far, my View function looks like this:

```
public ViewResult Index()  
{  
    var viewModel = from tr in db.TRs   
    join proj in db.Projects on tr.ProjectID equals proj.ProjectID   
    join templ in db.Templates on tr.TemplateID equals templ.TemplateID  
    orderby proj.ProjectName  
    select new  
    {  
        TRList = tr.TRID,  
        TemplateList = templ.TemplateName,  
        ProjectList = proj.ProjectName,  
        Version = tr.version  
    }   
    return View(viewModel); //Go in Index.cshtml  
}
```

And the View is:

```
@model IEnumerable <OnlineTR.WebUI.Areas.Admin.Models.TRManagerModel>  
@foreach (var item in Model)  
             {
            <tr>  
                <td>  
                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.TRList);  
                </td>  
                <td>  
                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.ProjectList);  
                </td>  
                <td>  
                   @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.TemplateList);  
                </td>  
            </tr>  
            }
```

I'm trying to find a way to use a sql request that only use what I need.

If you can show me how to use the .include, it would be awesome. So far I have try, but it doesn't accept lambda expressions in the (), it wants a string path. (maybe missing a using?)

Thanks a lot. Alex.

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  You haven't fully defined what your problem is.  You say "it doesn't accept lambda expressions in the ()".  What doesn't?  What's the ()? If you have an error please include that.

Comment: To use Include() with lambda expression, you need `using System.Data.Entity;`. But it is not clear, how it relates to the problem you are solving. Please, clarify your question.

Comment: Oh sorry. I did db.TR.Include(x => x.Project) and I got an error when compiling. It said that it was expecting a string path as an argument. Like db.TR.Include("Project") . This thing built, but return NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are passing IEnumerable of anonymous type to your view, but it expects the type

```
@model IEnumerable <OnlineTR.WebUI.Areas.Admin.Models.TRManagerModel>
```

Fix your LINQ query to select a concrete type, and it will work

```
select new TRManagerModel
    {  
        TRList = tr.TRID,  
        TemplateList = templ.TemplateName,  
        ProjectList = proj.ProjectName,  
        Version = tr.version  
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thks for the answer. I was able to fix my problem. I have fix the LINQ query. But my question is more : How would you approach that problem ? Would you use the same type of query ? Or would you use function like .include ? Would you use a different model ? The problem with a "newbie" like me , is that I get the result I want, but Im never too sure if its the best way to do it. So any new ideas is very welcome. Also, like I said, I tried to use .include (look cleaner to me! :) ) but it doesnt work. Its looking for a string path (not lambda).

Comment: `Include()` loads whole entities into the memory and provides change tracking. Both means an unnecessary overhead in your case. If you do not want to modify your model, using projection (i.e. select statment) is the best solution. Strange about your solution are the joins. In case of a properly defined model, you can use navigational properties instead of joining entities manualy.

Comment: Tks for the answer. Ill look forward to learn more about Navigational properties.